# recalculate currency by selection curency symbol from drop down box

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to recalculate the value every time user selects a currency from drop down box.

Example

column A   column B
product 1  25
product 2  34
product 3  16

lets assume that the value in column B is in Euro, I need to create a drop down box that contains EURO, USD, GBP and so on.
Every time I select one of the currency from drop down list I want column B to recalculate based on currency rate between Euro and the selected currency.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column for the converted values, calculated as the Euro values (ColumnB) multiplied by say E1:

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2*E$1,"")
```

with the formula in say D2 and copied down to suit. D1 might hold your drop-down list, driven from a lookup table that next to the currency indicator (immediately to the right) holds the conversion factor. Say that table is H1:I3, then in E1:

```
  =VLOOKUP(D1,H1:I3,2,0)
```

[image: SO29110827 example]

Comment: Hi pnuts, thank you for your answer. I tried it but not sure I am reading your instruction correctly.  I would attach my test spreadsheet but not sure if I can on here.